# which eclipse plugin I need for this?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have this ice face tag in my .jsp page:

```
<ice:panelPopup modal="true" rendered="true"
    visible="#{popupInfoMessageBean.showPopupPanel}"
    style="z-index:1001; width: 250px; height: 250px;">
```

When I press Ctrl + click on popupInfoMessageBean I do need to be redirected to that class.

Is there any plugin which does this? I know that in IDEA just enabling Facelets this problem is solved but what about Eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Installed JBoss Tools and added JSF capabilities.

[This](http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/283-java-server-faces/1858-auto-completion-of-icesoft-icefaces-tags-in-eclipse-helios.html) helped.